# How to select an option from the kendo dropdown using selenium webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" id="ddlSettleMode_listbox" aria-live="polite" data-role="staticlist" role="listbox"><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item k-state-selected k-state-focused" data-offset-index="0" id="18e2d509-b1e1-4588-bd2a-dcff29b45b83">Select</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="1">Cash</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="2">Card</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="3">Cheque</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="4">Paytm</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="5">NEFT</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="6">DD</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="7">IMPS</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="8">Online</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="9">UPI</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="10">Digital</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="11">CMS</li><li tabindex="-1" role="option" unselectable="on" class="k-item" data-offset-index="12">Univ</li></ul>
```

This is my selenium code:

```
WebDriverWait Waita = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        Waita.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'Select']")));
        Waita.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text() = 'Select']"))).click();
        WebDriverWait waitb = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        waitb.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[text() = 'Cash']")));
        waitb.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[text() = 'Cash']"))).click();
```

I'm getting the below error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //li[text() = 'Cash'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Comment: Did you try with adding a condition to check full page load and then access the drop down?

Comment: No i didn't...how to add condition to check full page load

Answer (score 0):

To select the item with text as **Cash** within the kendo dropdown using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) instead of using `` you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ul.k-list.k-reset#ddlSettleMode_listbox li.k-item[data-offset-index='0']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("li.k-item[data-offset-index='1']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='k-list k-reset' and @id='ddlSettleMode_listbox']//li[contains(@class, 'k-item') and text()='Select'][@data-offset-index='0']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@class='k-item' and text()='Cash'][@data-offset-index='1']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: the above solutions are not working for me    .... here by default the "Select" option will be there in the dropdown so i need to click the dropdown and again i need to select the Cash option

Comment: @MurugesanK Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.